# Issues outputting data after prepared statement with loops

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I am having some major difficulties figuring out what I am doing wrong in the while and foreach loops in the code below. I am having a tendency to mix object-oriented and procedural mqsqli, but everytime I think I have it right, I get an error.

What am I doing wrong in the loops I have in this code?

Right now I get this error

```
Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string,
```

Full code

```
try {
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new Exception("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
    echo $cid . "<br>";
    echo $tid;
//Prepare
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
    //$stmt->fetch();

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1){
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onclick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }

foreach($stmt as $row) {

    //Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum posts
    if($stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?")) {
    //var_dump($stmt2);

        $stmt2->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }   
    if ($result = $con->query($stmt)) {
        while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
            by ".$row2['post_creator']." - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr />" . $row2['post_content'] ."</div></td>
            <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
}
}       
}   else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the execute part when copying this in here. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1")) {

$stmt->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
//$stmt->fetch();

if (!$stmt) {
    throw new Exception($con->error);
}
}

    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
```

At no point do you actually execute the `$stmt` before you loop through the `foreach($stmt as $row) {`.

You'll want to throw this in there:

`$stmt->execute()`

Your logic is a little all over the place. You look like you're looping through the result of a query that you never execute, then you try to re-query the original `$stmt` here:

`if ($result = $con->query($stmt)) {`

EDIT: After chatting with you, you need to edit your original query to query specific columns so you can reference them like this:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT topic_creator FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1")) {
```

...

```
$stmt->bind_result($topic_creator); 
while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
   echo "TC: " . $topic_creator . "<br>"; 
}
```

You can take this and apply it to your sub queries within the `while` loop.

Comment: I actually commented that out on accident. When the execute is in it, it still gives the same error. What should it be then? I am really getting confused with this and cannot figure out where I am messing up at.

Comment: You are preparing your `$stmt`, but never actually executing the query. You need to do something like:http://pastebin.com/GRusBAfC

Comment: Also, make sure that your query is correct and your `$_GET` variables are populating your bind variables correctly.

Comment: I am executing the query. I know my problem is with my fetches, while loops and foreach. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong with them.. Here is my code, it has the execute in it, I just forgot to include it when asking the question. `$stmt->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
  
  $stmt->execute();`

Comment: My prepared statement checks out fine. The values of $cid and $tid and are coming through fine, I just can't figure out how to fetch and loop the results.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($stmt)` after the execute? If that is TRUE, then I would loop through the results like: http://pastebin.com/inqxfXSk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84006/discussion-between-paul-and-etm124).

Comment: I get this... `7object(mysqli_stmt)#9 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(2) ["field_count"]=> int(8) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }`